# Docusign Oauth token generation using API

Tags: c#, docusignapi

Currently i am using Docusign Demo account and there i generated a Oauth token from Docusign UI refer here(https://iodocs.docusign.com/), with the Oauth token was able to make all API calls to Docusign from code. My issue here is previously there was an API to generate to Outh token from 
here(https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Authentication/Authentication/). But, the API is now deprecated. Can any one suggest me where i can get the API to generate Oauth token.Else, what is the way to generate Oauth token from API using code.

Answer (score 0):

See the authentication section of docs.docusign.com for oauth info.

It is listed near the top of the navigation on the left.

Don't use the obsolete oauth methods in the iodocs site.

(sorry I can't provide exact links from this mobile. )

Comment: Here's the link to the "Authentication" section of the docs that Larry refers to in his answer: https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_overview.html